# How can one solve $1^x=2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, complex-numbers, exponentiation

Sure, common sense says there's no solution. But, I feel, there should be one! (If there isn't, can't we construct one?)

Comment: How about $x = \log_1(2)$? :-)

Comment: Common sense says that $1^x$ is well defined: actually it is not. So your equation makes no sense.

Comment: Which function $1^x$ are we talking about? $\exp (x\cdot 0)$, $\exp (x\cdot 2\pi i)$?

Comment: What makes you feel that there is a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real solution for the first question $1^x = 2$

For the second part:

Let $x = a+ib$ and $e^{(2n+1)i\pi} = -1 , n \in \Bbb Z $ so, $2^{a+ib} = 2e^{(2n+1)i\pi}$, so $2^{a-1 + ib} = e^{(2n+1)i\pi}$.

Take log and you will get, $(a-1+ib)\log2 = (2n+1)i\pi$.

Equating real and imaginary part, $a = 1, b = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{\log2}$. Thus

$$x = 1 + i\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{\log2}, n \in \Bbb Z.$$